# Guidance needed - GridSearchCV returns parameters that decrease the accuracy of the XGBoost model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost, gridsearchcv

I am playing around with the XGBoostClassifier and tuning this with GridSearchCV. I first created the variable xgbc:

```
xgbc = xgb.XGBClassifier()
```

I did'nt use any parameters as I wanted to see the default model performance. This gave me **accuracy_score = 85.65%**, **recall_score = 77.91%** and **roc_auc_score = 84.21%**, using the following lines of code:

```
print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_test, xgbc.predict(X_test)))
print("Recall: ", recall_score(y_test, xgbc.predict(X_test)))
print("ROC_AUC: ", roc_auc_score(y_test, xgbc.predict(X_test)))
```

Next, I used GridSearchCV to try to tune the parameters, like this:

Setting up the parameter dictionary:

```
xgbc_params = {'max_depth': [5, 6, 7], #6
               'learning_rate': [0.25, 0.300000012, 0.35], #0.300000012
               'gamma':[0, 0.001, 0.1], #0
               'reg_lambda': [0.8, 0.95, 1], #1
               'scale_pos_weight': [0, 1, 2], #1
               'n_estimators': [95, 100, 105]} #100
```

(The numbers after the # are the default values, which gave me the above scores.)

And now run the GridSearchCV like this:

```
xgbc_grid = GridSearchCV(xgbc, param_grid=xgbc_params, scoring = make_scorer(accuracy_score), cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
```

Next, fit this to the training data:

```
xgbc_grid.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose = 1, early_stopping_rounds = 10, eval_metric = 'aucpr', eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)])
```

Finally, run the metrics again:

```
print("Best Reg estimators: ", xgbc_grid.best_params_)
print("Accuracy: ", accuracy_score(y_test, xgbc_grid.predict(X_test)))
print("Recall: ", recall_score(y_test, xgbc_grid.predict(X_test)))
print("ROC_AUC: ", roc_auc_score(y_test, xgbc_grid.predict(X_test)))
```

Now, the scores change: **accuracy_score = 0.8340807174887892**, **recall_score = 0.7325581395348837** and **roc_auc_score = 0.8420896282464777**. Also, here is the `best_params_` result:

```
Best Reg estimators:  {'gamma': 0, 'learning_rate': 0.35, 'max_depth': 5, 'n_estimators': 95, 'reg_lambda': 0.8, 'scale_pos_weight': 1}
```

Here is my problem:

1. The parameter values that GridSearchCV returns through `xgbc_grid.best_params_` are not the most optimal for accuracy, as the accuracy score decreases. Can you please help me figure out why this is happenning?
2. In the parameter dictionary above, I have provided the default values. If I set the parameters to only these single values, then I get the 85% accuracy, like, `'max_depth': [6]`. However, as soon as I add other values, like `'max_depth': [5, 6, 7]`, then GridSearchCV gives the parameters that are not the highest on accuracy score. Full details below:

   ```
    Base Reg estimators (acc = 85%):  {'gamma': 0, 'learning_rate': 0.35, 'max_depth': 5, 'n_estimators': 95, 'reg_lambda': 0.8, 'scale_pos_weight': 1}

    Best Reg estimators (acc = 83%):  {'gamma': 0, 'learning_rate': 0.35, 'max_depth': 6, 'n_estimators': 100, 'reg_lambda': 1, 'scale_pos_weight': 1}
   ```

Comment: Any CV procedure by definition imposes some randomness to the problem, which may easily lead to discrepancies such as the ones you report here.